# Sails JS - Remove existing JWT

Tags: node.js, security, sails.js, token, jwt

I followed this tutorial https://ericswann.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/nozus-js-1-intro-to-sails-with-passport-and-jwt-json-web-token-auth/ and I got it working just fine. The only thing left missing is the logout functionallity. I read that I could just delete the token from the client side, but still I think it'd be a better approach to also remove it from the server.

This is my AuthController.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
//Triggers when user authenticates via passport
function _onPassportAuth(req, res, error, user, info) {
    if (error) return res.serverError(error);
    if (!user) return res.unauthorized(null, info && info.code, info && info.message);
    return res.ok({
        // TODO: replace with new type of cipher service
        token: HashService.createToken(user),
        user: user
    });
}

module.exports = {
    signup: function (req, res) {
        User.create(_.omit(req.allParams(), 'id')).then(function (user) {
            return {
                // TODO: replace with new type of cipher service
                token: HashService.createToken(user),
                user: user
            };
        }).then(res.created).catch(res.serverError);
    },

    signin: function (req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('local', _onPassportAuth.bind(this, req, res))(req, res);
    }
};
```

How can I destroy a token?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to destroy a token when I want to logout. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to destroy the token.

That's the idea of tokens - there is no signin\signup functionality, just tokens which can be verified (or not).

If you want to "logout" the user then just remove token from storage on client-side. Anyway, token will be valid until you change secret key or certificate, or when it expires.

**UPD:**

> but still I think it'd be a better approach to also remove it from the server.

Server is store nothing.

Comment: I get it. But what about a MongoDB collection for a token blacklist?

Comment: @ghaiklor I also want to know how to remove the token from the client-side when he make a request to the /logout route?

Comment: @Lexynux just delete it from the storage. What's the problem?